# Android getenv returns libNimsWrap.so

Tags: android, android-ndk

My ndk application checks LD_PRELOAD variable at start. And only on sony experia l getenv("LD_PRELOAD") returns "/system/lib/libNimsWrap.so" (with samsung returns NULL). How to start my app without this lib or why android preloads this? What is this library?

Comment: Looks like this is a Qualcomm Snapdragon customization. I have seen it on other devices with different varieties of MSM8*** SoC.

Comment: `What is this library?` I have same question but nobody knows apparently...